# How to get first item (product) of each user in database (Laravel)

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables in database, users and products, with one to many relationship. and I want to get first product created by each user. I tried a number of queries but cant complete it. any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you share the User model code ?

Comment: if you have a relation defined in user model you can get the latest product like this: `$user->products()->latest()->first();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first()` or  `->products()->latest()->first()`